# Regex on domain and negation against language subfolders

Tags: regex

Let's say my domains are:

- www.test.com
- www.test.com/en-gb
- www.test.com/cn-cn

These are language sites, the first is the main US English site. In Google Analytics I want to set up a filter to only show me traffic of the first (US) domain. I could do this, I think:

```
^\/(en-gb|cn-cn).*$
```

If I EXCLUDE my Request URI with that filter pattern, then I should get a view for the en-US domain. However, I'm interested in understanding regex better so here is some test data and code which I am trying out on http://www.regextester.com/

Regular expression:

```
^\/(en-gb|cn-cn).*$
```

Test String

```
/cn-cn/about
/cn-cn/about/
/cn-cn
/cn-cn/about/test
/en-gb/
/en-gb
/en-gb-test/
/en-gb/aboutus/
/en-gb?q=1
/en-gb/?q=1
/about-us
/test?q=1
/aword/me/
/three
/about/en-gb/
/about/en-gb-test/
/test-yes/
/test/me/
/hello/world/
```

My questions:

1. If you try this out, you'll notice that /en-gb-test/ is actually matched with the Regex. How do I avoid this?
2. Also, let's say I wanted to have a rule to NEGATE this whole option. So rather than telling Google Analytics to "exclude", I am curious how I could write the opposite of this same rule. So basically, catch all URLs that are not in /en-gb and /cn-cn sub-folders.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q2: It is not possible with GA RE2 regex. Q1: Try [`^\/(en-gb|cn-cn)([\/?].*|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/jzGlng/2)

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked! Let's say I was doing this on .htaccess - can you answer Q2 for that? I'm very curious.

Comment: Could you also tell me why the | at the end of your rule solved Q1? It does solve it - I just don't understand the semantics of the ending *|$

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment (I cannot edit it). Could you also confirm - the ? near the end of your rule for Q1 does not need to be escaped? I can see it doesn't but I do get confused when to escape and when not to escape. Would     `^\/(en-gb|cn-cn)([\/\?].*|$)` be equivalent to your rule - i.e. just with \? escaped?

Comment: The `[...]` is a character class where only 4 chars might need escaping: ``\``, `^`, `-` and `]`. Only ``\`` must be escaped in all positions. `]` does not need escaping when it is the first char in the char class. `-` does not need escaping when it is the first/last. And `^` must be escaped if it is the first char in the char class.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may stop the regex from matching `en-gb-test` by making sure you may `/` or `?` after it or the end of the string

```
^\/(en-gb|cn-cn)([\/?]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jzGlng/3). If you really need to get the rest of the string, add `.*` after `[\/?]`: `^\/(en-gb|cn-cn)([\/?]|$)`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a `/` (note that you do not need to escape `/` in GA regex)
- `(en-gb|cn-cn)` - a capturing group with 2 alternatives, either `en-gb` or `cn-cn`
- `([\/?]|$)` - a capturing group with two alternatives: a `?` or `/` OR the end of the string.

In RE2 regex, you cannot use lookaheads that are crucial when you need to match something other than something else. It would look like `^(?!\/(en-gb|cn-cn)([\/?]|$)).*`, but it is not possible with RE2.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much Wiktor! Very much appreciated!